# Rebooting Tizen display will often not cause update

Tags: javascript, tizen, reboot

we are developing a web application (HTML/CSS/JS) on Tizen SSSP4 and SSSP5 devices.

According to SAMSUNG changing tthe version number of the application in **sssp_config.xml** will cause the display to update next time the application is to be launched.

However when I update the app version and reboot the display using

```
b2bapis.b2bcontrol.rebootDevice
```

it will sometimes update, yet other times it will not. Usually it will not update on the first time, yet update if I call the same API once more after the display has restarted. Sometimes the display will get stuck and no longer update even if I reboot multiple times using the API.

I checked the web connection, which is fine. The display is connected via cable, between the display and my server is but a switch. Also I see the display in WEINRE using a webhook all the time.

Has anyone encountered this problem? What can be done to resolve this? Is there something that must be done when unloading the app in order to release the API properly?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find anything like this api b2bapis.b2bcontrol.rebootDevice! Are these closed api of Tizen ?

Comment: These are API for SAMSUNG displays, specifically we utilize these for signage applications. So yes, this rather specific, not Tizen in general. I asked SAMSUNG about this and apparently it is a serious issue on their end.

Comment: To clarify a bit more in case someone stumbles accross this question: We are working with SAMSUNG displays (basically TVs for specific purposes) which are based on the Tizen platform. They provide the usual Tizen-API functions as well as some additional ones, among which is the API call I described. Thus this is a Tizen question, however the case is very specific, as it is not applicable for wearables for example.

Comment: I am not seeing any public API for that ... so i am clueless